# How to download facebook user profile pic and upload it to my rails3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I have tried to retrieve user profile pic from facebook using omniauth. But it is providing an auth_hash which has a link in form of http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=normal. Please tell me how to download the image from the retrieved link and upload it to the signup page of my rails3 app.

Comment: You should consider using the given link in your page instead of downloading the image. This way, when the user will change his profile picture, your page will always display the current picture of your user.

Comment: Baldrick: But I need to upload that image into my signup page and for uploading I need that image in my local database. How to upload it?

Comment: As @Baldrick was pointing out, if you have the facebook user id provided by omniauth you can reference a user's profile picture by using the link http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=normal as the source of whatever img tag you have in the page. This way if the user changes their profile picture your app will always have the correct one. You also don't have to worry about storing and managing photos.